# Creating a function template for double and std::complex that does not require specialization

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, complex-numbers

As a learning exercise, I was trying to create a function that computes a Hermitian conjugate in-place. It should behave like a simple transpose when all entries are real, and hence should work with double. I know that I can specialize separately for double, and it's doable in this particular example. But, I imagine that specializing would become tedious for larger problems like ODE Solvers.

I tried the following

```
#include <complex>

const size_t ZERO = 0ul;

template <class value_type,
          class container_type = value_type*>
auto
hermitianConjugate(container_type buffer, size_t width)
{
    for (size_t row = ZERO; row < width; row++)
    {
        for (size_t col = ZERO; col < width; col++)
        {
            auto temp = std::conj(buffer[col * width + row]);
            if (std::imag(temp) == 0)
            {
                // works for both double and std::complex
                buffer[row * width + col] = buffer[col * width + row];
            } else 
            {
                // for std::complex
                buffer[row * width + col] = temp;
                // raises error when value_type is double
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround that does not involve explicit specialization? Is there any way to use conditional branching "statically", if that makes sense?

Comment: something like `if constexpr (is_value_type_complex_v<value_type>)`? (`if constexpr` is C++17, no std traits for that, you have to write your own).

Comment: Aside: `template<typename container_type>` would suffice? You don't use `value_type` anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `if-constexpr` if you have c++17. This essentially creates different specializations, without the need to write separate functions.

```
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

const size_t ZERO = 0ul;

template <class value_type,
          class container_type = value_type*>
auto
hermitianConjugate(container_type buffer, size_t width)
{
    for (size_t row = ZERO; row < width; row++)
    {
        for (size_t col = ZERO; col < width; col++)
        {
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<value_type, std::complex<double>>) {
                // only for complex
                buffer[row * width + col] = std::conj(buffer[col * width + row]);
            }
            else
            {
                // for double
                buffer[row * width + col] = buffer[col * width + row];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you do not have c++17, you could write an overloaded function to perform the different tasks, depending on the type:

```
#include <complex>

const size_t ZERO = 0ul;

constexpr double myconj(double x) noexcept { return x; }
std::complex<double> myconj(std::complex<double> x) { return std::conj(x); }

template <class value_type,
          class container_type = value_type*>
auto
hermitianConjugate(container_type buffer, size_t width)
{
    for (size_t row = ZERO; row < width; row++)
    {
        for (size_t col = ZERO; col < width; col++)
        {
            buffer[row * width + col] = myconj(buffer[col * width + row]);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that [std::conj](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/conj) has already a dedicated overload for double, but also in this case it returns a `std::complex`.